# PHP mail sending an email with colon in the message will not send the message

Tags: php, email, attachment

I am trying to send an email with an attachment, everything worked fine before. But then we switched servers and now it is not working anymore so I started debugging. And i came to the conclusion that if the message contains a **colon** the message will not be included in the email that is being send.

When I remove the colon the email sends everything including the message.

Could anyone tell me how the colon can interrupt the message being send ?

This is my current code:

```
$from_name = "From name";
$from_mail = "inbox@inbox.nl";
$replyto = "no-reply@email.nl";
$message = "This is a: test";
$content = "This is the content";
$subject = "Test";
$mailto = "receiver@provider.nl";
$bijlage_naam = "test.xml";
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
//$header .= $message."\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;         name=\"$bijlage_naam\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;         filename=\"$bijlage_naam\"\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
//$header .= "--".$uid."--";
if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since after you have changed the server things started failing, are you sure that the server doesn't have any problem?

Comment: @tcak No I don't think so because I can send mails witouth colon

Comment: @user3734231, I've been facing this problem since 3 days whitout knowing why the email is not sent, no error received, removing the colon from the subject fixed the issue, so I suggest you get rid of it, I have no explanation why actually but I read somewhere that the subject should not contain any special characters, so my guess is that the colon is causes a parsing error on the mail server, but somehow it's not returned as an error.

Comment: FYI: It turns out that the dash character also causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a colon will affect you to send a email or not.

But if you put your message in header

```
$header .= $message; //I found it in your code
```

There would be a problem because header uses `:` to define something.

What I can recommend you to do is split those colons with a `\`. There is a simple PHP function could do that:

```
$header .= str_replace(":", "\:", $message).
```

You can see if you are able to send it again or not.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I've tried to place a \ before the : but it still doesn't send. I also tried to remove the message from the headers and place it directly into the mail function. But then it still doesn't send with a :, and when I remove the : it does send. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Is your script returned 1? Maybe your new server do not allow you to send emails by php mail() because it will cause the server being blacklisted from RBL sites if there are some spam mailer. So the other suggestion is try this again on the other server to see if it can be sent or not. If it can, that means you should change another server.

Comment: No it isn't that because I already placed in my post that I could send emails with mail when there is no ':'. So it should be seomthing else

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your message in the header, but in the appropiate `$message` parameter...

Comment: I've changed the place of the message, I am now sending it in the mail function and not in the header anymore, but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @user3734231 I'd suggest to remove all fancy headers and attachments, try to send an absolutely basic mail and keep adding headers and stuff until it fails